# Child nodes of accessibilityNodeInfo AlertDialog is always null. How to get the button?

Tags: android

I'm developing an accessibility app and looking to auto click on a button on AlertDialog. Its done with permissions "Allow" button, but when i traverse through child nodes on a system AlertDialog (e.g. when you try to send an sms it ask for confirmation and i want to automate this).

```
    public void autoAllowSend(AccessibilityEvent event){
    AccessibilityNodeInfo accessibilityNodeInfo = event.getSource();
    if (accessibilityNodeInfo != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < accessibilityNodeInfo.getChildCount(); i++) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo child = accessibilityNodeInfo.getChild(i);
            if (child != null) {
                CharSequence text = child.getText();
                Logg("B", child.getClassName().toString());
            }else{
                Logg("A","Child is Null");
            }
        }
    }else{
        Logg("A","accessibilityNodeInfo is null.");
    }
}
```

I tried with List list = nodeInfo.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText("Send"); - its not showing it. on event.toString i can see the button and its text "Send" but accessibility cannot see this although it has all needed permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
int count = -1;
for (AccessibilityNodeInfo leaf : getLeaves(event)) {
    if (leaf.getClassName().toString().toLowerCase().contains("button")) {
        count++;
        if (count == index) {
            leaf.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
        }
    }
}
```